# How does JavaScript map() function iterate until the array size while it's having a return inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

First I need to say I am new to java script and react .So I need to clarify below code in detail.

```
  <ul>

      { this.state.tags.map(tag=>{
         return <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>}
      )}
  </ul>
```

In my react application I have an array called tags and here I am trying to map my array elements to some html element(list element) ,so the expected output is there,but I need to know how is that map function execute until it's last element when there is a return statement in the code.

I mean if you have a for each loop in java like this in a method if you call this method then you will get only 5 as the output because function will terminate in the first iteration of for each.So please explain how this is not true with js.

```
 public static Integer getfirstElement(){
        List<Integer> arr= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        arr.add(5);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(3);
        for(Integer temp : arr){
          return temp;

        }
        return 0;

 }
```

Comment: I advice would be don't jump into react or any other js framework until you have a solid foundation in basic javascript concepts otherwise it might be too much to take at once.

Comment: the map function is a callback function which gets called repeatedly (not once) for each element in your array. It's similar to calling a function in a loop when iterating on a new element, except JS performs the loop for you and builds an array with the return value of each function call

Answer (score 2):

The function inside the `map()` function as a second parameter is a **callback** function which `map()` calls it in every iteration.

As the `map` name says, the function maps (transforms) every item of array to the returned value from the callback.

It is like:

```js
function map(array, callback){
  const mappedArray = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    mappedArray[i] = callback(array[i])
  }
  return mappedArray;
}


function doubleTheValue(i){
   return i*2
}

const arr = [1,2,3]

const mapArr = map(arr, doubleTheValue)

console.log(mapArr)
```

Comment: thank you for you great explanation I really got it,but can you explain your code little bit more ,I mean what's that i value which you passed as an argument to the function(i) I mean how that i variable gets a value.

Comment: When you pass the function as a parameter, you are not passing the return value of the function. But you're passing the function itself (which is why it's called a callback function). I updated the answer. Defined the function outside and passed the function as a parameter (Note that when passing it as a callback, you should not use parentheses). When you call `map()`, it calls the function with `callback(value)`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not an equivalent of Java's `for`. It's an equivalent of [Stream map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), it returns a new `Array` that contains each element transformed with the provided `function`.